# Get method do not have time to pull data from the server

Tags: angular, http, observable

I have a very basic problem but I don't know the best way to do that. My problem is in on click on the button I want to send data and get the same data from the server. And in some situation, my backend can time to store data in my DB and when I retrieve data I pull without last changes.

```
  storeCategory() {
 this.categoryService.storeCategory(this.currentFileUpload, this.category).subscribe();  
this.adminService.getCategoryFromServer();
```

Does anyone know have a proposal?

Comment: Can your server return that data as a response to first request?

Comment: For that, I can change my method on the backend. Maby is that good solution.

Comment: I think it's the easiest and safest solution if you can do that

Comment: Thanks, I think so.

Comment: you can also pipe and do the getCategoryFromServer after storeCategory() i.e.  this.categoryService.storeCategory(this.currentFileUpload, this.category).pipe(map(() => this.adminService.getCategoryFromServer()).subscribe((data) => data)

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve the data when the storing has completed by putting `getCategoryFromServer()` inside the `subscribe()` of `storeCategory(this.currentFileUpload, this.category)`:

```
storeCategory() {

    this.categoryService.storeCategory(this.currentFileUpload, this.category)
    .subscribe(() => {

        this.adminService.getCategoryFromServer();

    });
}
```

This way you should get the latest changes.